# Overriding a global variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
        var min="1.2.2";          
        $.validator.addMethod('xyz', function(value, element, param) {        
                        alert(min);    
                        min=minAorB();// I want to call a function which will return the minimum among A and B.  
                        alert(min);    
                        return (validateAnmcComp(value,param));    
                        }, "Please enter a value less than or equal to "+min);  
        })(jQuery);
```

I want the message to be displayed as "Please enter a value less than or equal to 1.4.5"

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just change the value in the variable `min` above the function?

Comment: I have edited the code.
The min will store the value returned by the function minAorB().
In the second alert the value of min is changed,but while accessing in the message "Please enter...",the value is shown as 1.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this help?

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    function createMinValidator(min) {
        return function(value, element, param) {
            // use min as required
            return (validateAnmcComp(value, param));
        };
    }
    var min = "1.4.5";
    var msg = "Please enter a value less than or equal to " + min;
    $.validator.addMethod('xyz', createMinValidator(min), msg);
});
```